# Condition based counter of variables in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, function, counter, increment

I would like to rate error codes in a pandas dataframe according to their frequency of occurrence. If error_1 is in the error_code column, then the error_counter1 should be increased by 1. The same applies to error_2. To exclude the possibility that the error was an outlier, the variable unlearn_counter is increased by 1 for the value no_error. As soon as the unlearn_counter reaches 20, both variables error_counter1 and error_counter2 should be reset. However, as soon as error_counter1 exceeds the number 5, a 1st degree error should be detected and entered in the column error_type. As soon as error_counter2 exceeds the number 5, a 1st degree error should also be entered in the error_type column. If the sum of both variables error_counter1 and error_counter2 exceeds the value 5, a 1st degree error should also be entered in the column error_type. If the error_counter2 exceeds the value 10, a 2nd degree error should be entered in the error_type column. Here is the dataset for testing the function.

```
df_raw = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "index": [
            1,
            2,
            3,
            4,
            5,
            6,
            7,
            8,
            9,
            10,
            11,
            12,
            13,
            14,
            15,
            16,
            17,
            18,
            19,
            20,
            21
        ],
        "ID": [
            "A",
            "A",
            "A",
            "A",
            "A",
            "A",
            "A",
            "A",
            "A",
            "A",
            "A",
            "A",
            "A",
            "B",
            "B",
            "B",
            "B",
            "B",
            "B",
            "B",
            "B",
        ],
        "error_type": [
            "error_1",
            "error_1",
            "error_1",
            "error_1",
            "no_error",
            "no_error",
            "no_error",
            "no_error",
            "error_1",
            "error_1",
            "error_1",
            "error_1",
            "error_1",
            "error_2",
            "error_2",
            "error_2",
            "no_error",
            "no_error",
            "no_error",
            "error_2",
            "error_2",
            
        ],
    }
)
```

```
def error_degree_check(
    df,
    error_counter1 =0,
    error_counter2 =0,
    unlearn_counter=0,
    error_degree=0,
):
    dict = {}
    for ID in df["ID"].unique():
        df1 = df[df["ID"] == ID]
        for i, row in df1.iterrows():
                if row["error_type"] == "no_error":
                    unlearn_counter += 1
                elif row["error_type"] == "error_1":
                    error_counter1 += 1
                elif row["error_type"] == "error_2":
                    error_counter2 += 1
        if unlearn_counter > 5:
            error_counter1 == 0
            error_counter2 == 0
        elif error_counter1 > 5:
            error_degree  == 1
        elif error_counter2 > 5:
            error_degree  == 1
        elif (counter_limit_1 + counter_limit_2) > 5:
            error_degree == 1
        elif counter_limit_2 > 10:
            error_degree  == 2
        dict[row["ID"]] = error_degree 
    return pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict, orient="index", columns=["error_degree"])
```

So far, the following code has shown that no errors occur. But this can't be. Can somebody help me with that?

Comment: Your `if ... elif` block is using the comparison operator `==` rather than the assignment operator `=`. Could that be your issue?

Comment: Hm you are right but then I new error occurs. Maybe the row assignment is not the right syntax @ProfessorPantsless .

Comment: The syntax error probably comes from trying to do `+=` to the `error_counter` variables, since they have not been initialized in the function.

Comment: @ProfessorPantsless thanks for the hint. It was a copy paste error. Now there are initialized. But the error is still there.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the output you get and the expected/desired output? The code in your question still uses `==` and I am not sure if you are still running it with that in your code.